# What is the point of Collection<?>

Tags: java

I have been reading Effective Java and I have come across the unbounded Collection type `<?>`. However, the reading has led me to believe that you can't put any elements, other than `null`, into an instance of `Collection<?>`.

So, my question is this: what is the purpose of instantiating a `Collection<?>` when we can only insert `null` elements as it seems pointless. I've been trying to figure out this concept, but it just doesn't seems to make much sense. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I thought that Effective Java says that Collection<?> is type safe.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Collection<?>` allows you to create, among other things, methods that accept any type of `Collection` as an argument. For instance, if you want a method that returns `true` if any element in a `Collection` equals some value, you could do something like this:

```
public boolean collectionContains(Collection<?> collection, Object toCompareTo) {
    for (Object o : collection) {
        if (toCompareTo.equals(o)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This method can be called by any type of `Collection`:

```
Set<String> strings = loadStrings();
collectionContains(strings, "pizza");

Collection<Integer> ints = Arrays.toList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
collectionContains(ints, 1337);

List<Collection<?>> collections = new ArrayList<>();
collectionContains(collections, ILLEGAL_COLLECTION);
```

Comment: You mean methods rather than functions.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following Util method [from docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html)

> The following method shows you how to use an Iterator to filter an arbitrary Collection — that is, traverse the collection removing specific elements.

```
static void filter(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Iterator<?> it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (!cond(it.next()))
            it.remove();
}
```

This simple piece of **code is polymorphic**, which means that it works for any `Collection` regardless of **implementation**.

Answer (score 1):

When you are declaring a collection with wildcards you specify that the collection is a supertype of all kind of collections.

This is really useful when you have a method on which you would want to pass all types of collection let's say for example:

```
void printCollection(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Object e : c) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Have a look at [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) about wild cards as it's very exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

`Collection` is a lowest abstraction of all `Lists` and `Sets`. It is good to use as lowest abstraction you can use, cuz it gives you more flexibility in future and your code is more robust, cuz it can handle all `Lists` or `Sets` or other implementations, which do not even have to be implemented yet.

Well, Collection is some way equivalent to `Collection<Object>`. It just mean the generic type of the objects stored in `Collection` is **unknown** or you can use lowest abstraction of any object which is `Object` itself. In this case you can put into `Collection` any object even mix it with different types. But you have to be aware to cast it into proper type at runtime because you did not provide what type of Object your Collection is storing. So, the Collection cannot cast the Object to proper type for you, you have to do it by yourself. To recognize proper type you should use `Object instanceof SomeOtherClass` or `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)` at runtime.

Also `Collection` does not implement `get()` method but you can get `Iterator` and obtain object from the collection this way.