# Collection generics unable to add objects of defined type

Tags: java, generics

I have created 2 objects: `Person` and `Men` (extends `Person`). Then I created a generic collection to add only the `Men` objects, but for some reason it's not allowing me to add the Men object.

```
class Person{

}

class Men extends Person{

}

public class test extends HashSet<Person>{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<? extends Person> p1 = new ArrayList<Men>();
        p1.add(new Men());

    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics: What is PECS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Answer (score 7):

`List<? extends Person>` means "a `List` of some concrete type that extends `Person`, but we don't know what that concrete type actually is". For all we know, it could be a `List<Women>`! For this reason, you can't actually add *anything* to this list (except `null`). You likely want:

```
List<Men> p1 = new ArrayList<Men>();  // a list of only Men instances
```

See also: [Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: @Arshaji: So, what is the point of <? extends Person>, a women could be person..similaryly if I give for ex :- <? extends Object> = List<Integer>, a String could be extended from Object...so I can't add it...

Comment: @user1050619 YOu will have to use the super keyword for it with wildcard. You can read this link http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/28/generics-the-wildcard-operator/

Comment: @user1050619 I would suggest taking a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329944/what-is-the-point-of-collection/

Comment: @user1050619 You would use `<? extends SomeClass>` when you don't care what the concrete type is, but only care that it is a subclass of `SomeClass` - i.e. you're interested in for e.g. using a method defined in `SomeClass` on all of the elements of the list.

Answer (score 0):

make it `List<? super Men> p1 = new ArrayList<Men>();`. You can read about [Polymorphism and generics](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/28/generics-the-wildcard-operator/)

Comment: @user1050619, I am really glad it helped you :)